# Android - Action Bar Overflow

Tags: android

I'm really new to android development - I've been creating an action bar and its functioning, however it is going straight into my overflow although there is space for it to display?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: android:showAsAction="always"

Answer (score 1):

For API 11 and above you can use `android:showAsAction` tag for each item. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Use `android:showAsAction="always"` or `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` etc for each item as per your need.

Comment: sorry its not letting me post my code but I have done so and it just comes up in my overflow with all the items i have added

Comment: So it helped achieve what you want?

Comment: unfortunately not, <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always" /> - that is what i have per item but they are automatically being placed in the overflow on the emmulator with text 'Search' etc.

Comment: If you have lots of items then all might not be able to fit on the top bar. What happens when you do `ifRoom`?

Comment: What API version are you using?